# Cookies, server time vs client time

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a very weird case here

**A:**

1. i set my cookies expiry date by using System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)
2. client PC date time is faster than server date time by 1 hour

Scenario 1:

- use google chrome to try the webpage
- webpage take the CLIENT date time to set the expiry date of the cookies
- no problem either if the client date time is slower than server date time either

Scenario 2:

- use internet explorer to try the webpage
- webpage take the SERVER date time to set the expiry date of the cookies, but because the client date time is faster than server date time by 1 hour, cookies expired immediately.
- problem solved IF change the client date time same as or slower than server date time.

**B:**

1. set cookie by getting client date time by using javascript and ASP:hiddenField
2. Client PC date time is faster than server date time by 1 hour

Scenario 1:

- List item
- use google chrome to try the webpage
- no problem.
- but cookies expired immediately if client date time is slower than server date time

Scenario 2:

- use internet explorer to try the webpage
- no problem no matter the client date time is faster or slower than server date time

any advice to solve this? been bother me for last 2 weeks :(

P/S: Server time is +8 GMT. My client side is also +8 GMT but with 1 hour faster

Comment: What are you using this cookie for?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use client date time at all, it might be wrong. Best thing to do in your case is to use UTC Date time rather than client or server date time since UTC time is same everywhere.

Use `System.DateTime.UTCNow.AddSeconds(30)`.

In javascript, if needed, use UTC Date like :

`var isoDate = new Date('yourdatehere').toISOString();`

Comment: My read of it was that the client computer thinks that **UTC** is at some other time (an hour ahead), _not_ that it's a different time zone.  Still, this is probably a good recommendation in general (or just flat out setting the server to UTC).

Comment: That can be a case in Javascript, but in C# code System.DateTime.UTCNow will always work fine.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the input. i tried with UTC time, but my IE still cannot login :( the cookies expired immediately.

Comment: Server time is +8 GMT. My client side is also +8 GMT but with 1 hour faster

Comment: Just inquisitive why are you using cookies for such a small time, generally persistent cookies are used for bigger time-frame like one day or a week, general approach for small period is to use session time-out for 30sec(or required time  value) & remove all cookies on session time-out.

Comment: thx for the reply again. the purpose im using cookies is to share the value among different projects. I have 1 main-project and many sub-project. if the main page of the main-project is closed, then the sub-project(browser tab/browser windows) will closed automatically. 
main-project will auto update(every 20seconds) the cookies expiry date as long as the page is active. sub-project page will check if either the cookies is active, if expired, will auto closed the tab/windows.
do you have any better idea to solve this?

Comment: You said `1 main-project and many sub-project`, does it mean these are  differently hosted virtual directories/Websites?

Comment: yes, different projects and different paths. that's why i use cookies instead of session. every project is using different session, i can't share the value.

Comment: Got it :), this is very fine case for using cookies. I have also faced a issue like that. Please ensure your cookie is shared for all sites & domain for all cookies is same or not

Comment: yes, i can ensure they are using the same cookies. if u refer back my question, problem only occurs if using internet explorer if i use System.DateTime.UTCNow.AddSeconds(30); or DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)

Comment: In my case problem was with firefox & chrome and IE was working fine The solution was to add same domain name to Cookie. I don't know that's possible in your case or not. But yes, at first, I also think this is a browser problem but in my case it wasn't. Also what do you meant by `My client side is also +8 GMT but with 1 hour faster`?

Comment: What do you meant by add same domain name to Cookie? i tot the domain is auto generate when u create a new cookies? regarding with that question: server date Time is 1 Dec 2013 9:00am(+8 GMT). Client date time is 1 Dec 2013 10:00am(+8 GMT)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43492/discussion-between-pranav-and-melvintcs)

Comment: Discussion is getting lengthy, lets move to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43492/discussion-between-pranav-and-melvintcs